# Finding the version of OSX inside java

Tags: java, macos, version

I need to test if the version of osx is < 10.5 inside java is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
System.getProperty("os.name")
```

and/or

```
System.getProperty("os.version")
```

It returns String

[HERE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) you can find more info about System.getProperties

Answer (score 3):

Use [System.getProperty](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)).

```
System.getProperty("os.version");
```

The list of valid arguments for the function can be found [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties())

Comment: As always, when down-voting please say why. I am also here to learn, so if there is something wrong with my answer I would love to know.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [System](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) getProperties method can get that information for you.  See "os.version"

Answer (score 1):

`System.getProperty("os.version")`

Should return a string with three values for OS X, like: 10.5.1

You can also do `System.getProperty("os.name")` to make sure it's OS X in the first place