# Java - How can i determine the running Mac OS X version with code?

Tags: java, macos, osx-lion, version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the version of OSX inside java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799268/finding-the-version-of-osx-inside-java)

I want to check the current Mac OS X version my Java application is running on using Java code. Specifically, i want to know if this is Lion or not.

That way i can determine if to use a library or not.

Comment: @millimoose .. I apologize. I have searched a lot and did not find that.

Comment: No problem, the comment is autogenerated when flagging the question as a duplicate. I believe moderators can merge duplicate questions after the fact anyway.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use:

```
System.getProperty("os.name") // Yields "Mac OS X"
System.getProperty("os.version") // Yields "10.7.4" for me on Lion
```

Answer (score 5):

You can look at the system property `os.version`
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the following:

```
System.getProperty("os.name");
```

You can find more details at "[System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)".